# Open Excel in Browser using Asp.Net or Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

Hi is it possible to open an  Excel in browser, where the user can edit and save his changes. But wont be able to have a local copy of the said excel?

Thanks

Comment: It is _very_ complicated task. Are you sure that you want exactly this?

Comment: In response to your second requirement about the local copy: how do you intend to be able to edit something on the client without sending this something to the client? Alternatively you may checkout [Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/spreadsheets/) which allow you to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, for your comments, for the second requirement. They want that a user dont have a local copy of the excel cause it would be confidential. My first idea was to create a input form where they can input the values and just insert them to the excel file using interop. Sadly the excel file is more complicated than I though and they would possibly need to view the whole workbook. Thanks